# Outlook attachments and Javascript

Tags: javascript, security, outlook, internet-explorer-8

So I have a security issue with my fresh install of Outlook 2003 (on Windows 7 + Internet Explorer 8).  I just received an email with an HTML page attached.  I (stupidly) double clicked the attachment, which opened up IE, and which contained javascript that ran and took me to a malware site.

Some interesting facts:

(1) When I create an html file with javascript in it on my desktop and double click it, IE correctly refuses to execute the script.
(2) When I send this html file to myself and open it, IE executes it!

It seems to have something to do with the magical folder C:\Users(username)\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\OLK48

Why does it work this way?  What setting do I change to fix this?

Comment: This should be on serverfault or superuser.

Answer (score 0):

If i'm not mistaken you just got pwn3d by the [Help Centre 0-day](http://seclists.org/fulldisclosure/2010/Jun/205).  0-day means that it hasn't been fixed,  so the only way to prevent this from happening is by **stop using IE**.  If you care about security use Chrome,  IE has by far the worst security track record of any browser.

You should also be running and Anti-virus,  if you poor/cheap then use AVG.